# Finding the path to .lyx directory in order to install a package

Tags: lyx, windows

I'm trying to use the `PGFPlots` package in order to create some graphs on `LyX`. I'm following this tutorial ([link](http://www.chelseas-roost.co.uk/resources/lyx/PlottingGraphsInLyX)). It told to insert `\usepackage{pgfplots}` in the Latex Preamble section, so I did. Also I entered the following code in a `TeX` box:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But it shows nothing. So I guess the package is not installed and I have to install it. After some research, I understood that I need to find the `.lyx` directory and insert the package into the `modules` directory. But how can I find the `.lyx` directory? I tried to check the home directory `~` but didn't find it there. Is it possible to somehow find the path to that directory?

Comment: guessing that you are using MikTeX, first test if some simple plot example in LateX from this site works on TeXworks. If still the package is not found, try again but  after some minutes,  as maybe MikTeX could be now installing automatically. If still do not work, try to install it manually (but in MikTeX, not in LyX). Once it works in Texworks, go to LyX > Tools > Reconfigure. Then try to reproduce the same example in LyX.

Comment: Putting a LaTeX package in the LyX modules directory is a bit weird, as a LaTeX package is not a LyX module. They're quite different things. I don't know which TeX distribution (MikTeX, MacTeX, TeX Live) you've installed, but the "proper" way would be to use the package manager of that distribution. That said, if `pgfplots` was not installed in the first place, you should get an error when generating the PDF I'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The `Help→About` LyX dialog contains information about where your user directory is:

[image]

Also, if you use windows, `~` is `%userprofile%`.